# Colors in Node.js Winston logger v3.x

Tags: node.js, winston

Cant get any colors in console from Winston logger v3.x

```
const winston = require('winston')
const logLevels = {
  levels: {
    emerg: 0,
    alert: 1,
    crit: 2,
    error: 3,
    warning: 4,
    notice: 5,
    info: 6,
    debug: 7
  },
  colors: {
    emerg: 'red',
    alert: 'red',
    crit: 'red',
    error: 'red',
    warning: 'yellow',
    notice: 'blue',
    info: 'green',
    debug: 'green'
  }
}
winston.addColors(logLevels)
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  levels: logLevels.levels,
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.simple(),
      colorize: true
    })
  ]
});
logger.info('server starting...', {date: new Date()})
```

Did this snippet according to documentation on github page https://github.com/winstonjs/winston

No colors though

Answer (score 3):

try to use `combine` method to format:

```
 winston.format.combine(
      winston.format.colorize(),
      winston.format.simple()
    );
```

The colorize formatter must come before any formatters adding text you wish to color. hope it helps.
[reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston#colorizing-standard-logging-levelshttps://)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but I believe winston.addColors(logLevels) should be winston.addColors(logLevels.colors)